# spfx modern ui extension(Custom menu only showing in pages under sitepages)?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I successfully deployed my custom menu using application customizer(extension) but I noticed the menu only shows up when i view pages under sitepages.
It doesn't come up when viewing list and document libraries.
Is this how its suppose to work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Application Customizers work on Modern Pages. Are your listviews set to Classic mode (do they have a ribbon)?

Comment: THanks theChrisKent .No my list views are not set to classic but modern view.I know app customiser work on moder pages but when I go to list view in modern ui I don't see my custom menu.CHeers

Answer (score 2):

Its all about where are you registering the custom menu, basically if you want to have your custom actions in a list / doc lib, you need to use a List View Command set, where you need to set the proper location, so where the commands are displayed. The possible values are:

- **ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.ContextMenu**: The context menu of the 
  item(s).
- **ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet.CommandBar**: The top command set menu in a list or library.
- **ClientSideExtension.ListViewCommandSet**: Both the context menu and the command bar (corresponds to SPUserCustomAction.Location="CommandUI.Ribbon").

Resulting in having your commands in the list menu like shown here:

[image]

Take a look at the following article: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api#debugging-your-listview-command-set-using-gulp-serve-and-query-string-parameters

Comment: Hi Xavi, I wasn't referring to list menu etc.. I'm talking about a custom menu I built (Top Navigation Menu) . Does this make sense?

Comment: Hi @naijacoder absolutely, it makes total sense.  I would check, first, that you are using the proper placeholder in the page (should be the top placeholder): https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions. Second, if the page placeholder is OK, I found that there is an open issue in SPFx that can be totally related with what you are reporting: https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/1042. The issue is still open, unfortunately. If you think this is still not related, please post your code for more accurate help.

Comment: Thanks Xavi for your response.
 I can view the menu when in viewing a custom page.But still not in Listviews.
I can also notice these errors:_
listview-host-assembly_en-us_13b14d3769d9ebe3f5ae032d6ea2b0fe.js:208 Uncaught (in promise) Error: ***Failed to load path dependency "bootstrap" from component "" (SiteNavigationBsApplicationCus).
Any ideas what could be wrong?
I have the below in my config.json
 "bootstrap": {
      "path": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js",
      "globalName": "bootstrap",
      "globalDependencies": ["jquery"]
    },